# My Java Swing Designer calculator won't work. (The equals button for loop gives an error when pressed)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, calculator

```
package calculator;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.DefaultComponentFactory;

public class CalculatorWindow {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CalculatorWindow window = new CalculatorWindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public CalculatorWindow() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        final JLabel outputBox = new JLabel("");
        outputBox.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        outputBox.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        outputBox.setBounds(12, 39, 424, 112);
        frame.getContentPane().add(outputBox);

        JButton one = new JButton("1");
        one.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                outputBox.setText(outputBox.getText() + "1");
            }
        });
        one.setBounds(12, 163, 55, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(one);

        JButton two = new JButton("2");
        two.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                outputBox.setText(outputBox.getText() + "2");
            }
        });
        two.setBounds(77, 163, 55, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(two);

        JButton three = new JButton("3");
        three.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                outputBox.setText(outputBox.getText() + "3");
            }
        });
        three.setBounds(144, 163, 55, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(three);

        JButton four = new JButton("4");
        four.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                outputBox.setText(outputBox.getText() + "4");
            }
        });
        four.setBounds(12, 200, 55, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(four);

        JButton five = new JButton("5");
        five.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                outputBox.setText(outputBox.getText() + "5");
            }
        });
        five.setBounds(77, 200, 55, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(five);

        JButton six = new JButton("6");
        six.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                outputBox.setText(outputBox.getText() + "6");
            }
        });
        six.setBounds(144, 200, 55, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(six);

        JButton seven = new JButton("7");
        seven.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                outputBox.setText(outputBox.getText() + "7");
            }
        });
        seven.setBounds(12, 237, 55, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(seven);

        JButton eight = new JButton("8");
        eight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                outputBox.setText(outputBox.getText() + "8");
            }
        });
        eight.setBounds(77, 237, 55, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(eight);

        JButton nine = new JButton("9");
        nine.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                outputBox.setText(outputBox.getText() + "9");
            }
        });
        nine.setBounds(144, 237, 55, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(nine);

        JButton zero = new JButton("0");
        zero.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                outputBox.setText(outputBox.getText() + "0");
            }
        });
        zero.setBounds(207, 237, 55, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(zero);

        JButton add = new JButton("+");
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                outputBox.setText(outputBox.getText() + " + ");
            }
        });
        add.setBounds(207, 200, 55, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(add);

        JButton subtract = new JButton("-");
        subtract.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                outputBox.setText(outputBox.getText() + " - ");
            }
        });
        subtract.setBounds(207, 163, 55, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(subtract);

        JButton multiply = new JButton("x");
        multiply.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                outputBox.setText(outputBox.getText() + " x ");
            }
        });
        multiply.setBounds(274, 163, 55, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(multiply);

        JButton divide = new JButton("÷");
        divide.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                outputBox.setText(outputBox.getText() + " ÷ ");
            }
        });
        divide.setBounds(274, 200, 55, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(divide);

        JButton equals = new JButton("=");
        equals.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String[] outputBoxButtonsPressed = outputBox.getText().split(
                        " ");
                int answer;

                for (int buttonPressed = 0; buttonPressed < outputBoxButtonsPressed.length; buttonPressed++) {
                    if (outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed + 1].equals("+")) {
                        answer = Integer
                                .parseInt(outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed])
                                + Integer
                                        .parseInt(outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed + 2]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        equals.setBounds(274, 237, 55, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(equals);

        JLabel lbTitle = DefaultComponentFactory.getInstance().createTitle(
                "Calculator - Coded by William Bryant (gogobebe2)");
        lbTitle.setFont(new Font("Andale Mono", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lbTitle.setBounds(12, 12, 424, 15);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lbTitle);

        JLabel img = new JLabel("");
        Image theImage = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(
                "/calculatorIcon.png")).getImage();
        img.setIcon(new ImageIcon(theImage));
        img.setBounds(336, 163, 100, 106);
        frame.getContentPane().add(img);

    }
}
```

I think it's something in the if statement of the equals button handler in the for loop 
that causes the error.

This is the error message when I press the buttons "3", "3", "+", "6, "6" (which looks as 33 + 66 in the calculator outputbox):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at calculator.CalculatorWindow$16.actionPerformed(CalculatorWindow.java:198)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Any help is very much appreciated. I'm new to swing, awt and java.

Comment: About as straightforward as it gets. `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means you are trying to access an element of an array which doesn't exist.

Comment: place System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outputBoxButtonsPressed)); at the place where you first assign it to see what's in there.

Comment: I took out the for loop to debug it inside actionPerformed() and typed 2 + 1 and the print was [2, +, 1] like it should be. I don't understand why it is somehow trying to access an element of an array which doesn't exist??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop is problematic:

```
for (int buttonPressed = 0; buttonPressed < outputBoxButtonsPressed.length; buttonPressed++) {
    if (outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed + 1].equals("+")) {
        answer = Integer
            .parseInt(outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed])
             + Integer
                 .parseInt(outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed + 2]); //here
        break;
    }
 }
```

Specifically, the error occurs on the commented line when `buttonPressed` > =`outputBoxButtonsPressed.length - 2` because you're accessing the array up to two elements past where it ends. You can prevent the error by changing your loop condition to `buttonPressed < outputBoxButtonsPressed.length - 2`, but I'm not sue if this will stop your code from working or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String[] outputBoxButtonsPressed = outputBox.getText().split(
            " ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outputBoxButtonsPressed));
    int answer = 0;
    boolean firstOperatorBeenUsed = false;

    for (int buttonPressed = 0; buttonPressed < outputBoxButtonsPressed.length - 2; buttonPressed++) {
        if (outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed + 1].equals("+")
                && !firstOperatorBeenUsed) {
            answer = answer
                    + Integer
                            .parseInt(outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed])
                    + Integer
                            .parseInt(outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed + 2]);
            System.out.println(answer);
            firstOperatorBeenUsed = true;
        } else if (outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed + 1]
                .equals("+") && firstOperatorBeenUsed) {
            answer = answer
                    + Integer
                            .parseInt(outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed + 2]);

        }
        if (outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed + 1].equals("-")
                && !firstOperatorBeenUsed) {
            answer = answer
                    + Integer
                            .parseInt(outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed])
                    - Integer
                            .parseInt(outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed + 2]);
            System.out.println(answer);
            firstOperatorBeenUsed = true;
        } else if (outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed + 1]
                .equals("-") && firstOperatorBeenUsed) {
            answer = answer
                    - Integer
                            .parseInt(outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed + 2]);

        }

        if (outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed + 1].equals("x")
                && !firstOperatorBeenUsed) {
            answer = answer
                    + Integer
                            .parseInt(outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed])
                    * Integer
                            .parseInt(outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed + 2]);
            System.out.println(answer);
            firstOperatorBeenUsed = true;
        } else if (outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed + 1]
                .equals("x") && firstOperatorBeenUsed) {
            answer = answer
                    * Integer
                            .parseInt(outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed + 2]);

        }

        if (outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed + 1].equals("÷")
                && !firstOperatorBeenUsed) {
            answer = answer
                    + Integer
                            .parseInt(outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed])
                    / Integer
                            .parseInt(outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed + 2]);
            System.out.println(answer);
            firstOperatorBeenUsed = true;
        } else if (outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed + 1]
                .equals("÷") && firstOperatorBeenUsed) {
            answer = answer
                    / Integer
                            .parseInt(outputBoxButtonsPressed[buttonPressed + 2]);

        }

    }
    outputBox.setText(outputBox.getText() + " = " + answer);
}
```

Is this new equals button handler which works perfectly with all buttons. Yay :D